# cypress-testrail-accumulative-reporter is generating the multiple test run as per the number of parallel threads

Tags: automation, cypress, browserstack, testrail

I am using cypress-testrail-accumulative-reporter in my cypress automation project for testrail integration. I am executing the automation with 2 parallel thread against browserstack. Problem i am facing is that it is creating two testruns with all test cases and mark few of them pass and few of them are untested in each test run. I want it should create only one testrun for each execution with any number of parallel threads. Can some one have solution for the same.

Comment: Can anyone have any work around would be very helpful for me. Please reply.

Answer (score 0):

We updated suits in Test rail to match each run. Didn't find any other solution.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.It will not work as we need to create test run during execution and don't which specs will execute under which thread. there not any fix thing of execution in parallel thread.